# Pass class to Woocommerce shortcode [relative_products]

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode

I've been using Woocommerce shortcodes alot these days (Woocommerce 3.8).

For a lot of them you can pass "class" as a value - for example products shortcode: `[products class="custom-class"]` and then the wrapper of the returned content will have `custom-class`.

**But not for [reltative_products]!!??**

Very useful if you have a dynamic design and would like to be able to change the design of your relative products based on what content is being showed on your page.

If you look in the bottom of [the Woocommerce Docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Shortcodes.html#630-662) you can see the function:

```
    public static function related_products( $atts ) {
        if ( isset( $atts['per_page'] ) ) {
            $atts['limit'] = $atts['per_page'];
        }

        // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'limit'    => '4',
            'columns'  => '4',
            'orderby'  => 'rand',
        ), $atts, 'related_products' );
        // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd

        ob_start();

        // Rename arg.
        $atts['posts_per_page'] = absint( $atts['limit'] );

        woocommerce_related_products( $atts );

        return ob_get_clean();
    }
```

As you see there is no class in the shortcode_atts???

**How to change this?**

Comment: As a rule, the community considers questions about third-party plugins (such as woocommerce) off-topic so you might notice some down-votes and answers may be slow if they come at all. You can find out what questions are a good fit [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Okay. Thank you the notice. I was just wondering what the wocoomerce tag is for then?
Is it just hundreds like me who was off topic?

Comment: you are not alone in wondering this. There is a bit of an ongoing debate on this topic in meta. Anyone with enough rep can remake the tags and no one seems quite sure what we can do to make it clear. That's why I make a point of commenting on new posts when I am on the site. Personally, I'm all for opening up to some 3rd party but the long-standing users got a bit burned when this was tried before I was even here.

Answer (score 1):

**I have found a solution but i am not sure how good it is**

#### 1) Copy the shortcode into your functions.php

If you copy the function from the above [link to Woocommerce Docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Shortcodes.html#630-662) and create a your own shortcode (it_related_products_function) with it and then add `'class' => ''` to the arguments you can now pass 'class' to your shortcode.

```
function it_related_products_function( $atts ) {
 if ( isset( $atts['per_page'] ) ) {
   $atts['limit'] = $atts['per_page'];
 }

 $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
   'limit'    => '4',
   'columns'  => '4',
   'orderby'  => 'rand',
   'class'    => '',
 ), $atts, 'related_products' );

 ob_start();

 $atts['posts_per_page'] = absint( $atts['limit'] );

 woocommerce_related_products( $atts );

 return ob_get_clean();

}
```

#### 2) Grab the attribute in your `related.php` and echo if is set

```
    <section class="woocommerce columns-4 <?php echo !empty($class) ? $class : "" ?>">
```

#### 3) Now you can use your custom shortcode with 'class' anywhere

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[it_related_products limit="4" class="row it-books-fp red-border-bottom"]'); ?>
```